# MYSQL select that exlude duplicates with same value in row

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

I'm trying to create `SELECT` that exludes "duplicates"
The "duplicates" have difrent value in one column.

```
SELECT * from table where column1=3 and column1 not like 5
```

But it's not working

Comment: Use `<>` ([ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html)) to replace the `not like` (is used in strings). So, `SELECT * from table where column1=3 and column1<>5`

Comment: You can use some aggregation with `group by`. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html

Comment: Sample data and expected result please.